# Uvicorn: ''uvicorn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, uvicorn

I've been attempting to install Uvicorn for use with FastAPI, on Windows 10.

I'm encountering an error when running from the command prompt that reads
`'uvicorn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I'm running Python 3.10.7, with the following in my PATH environment variable

```
C:\Python310\   
C:\Python310\Scripts
```

I've attempted to install Uvicorn with pip using either of the following, including an uninstall between versions, uninstalling both and trying again, etc.

```
pip install uvicorn
pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

This does not appear to place a `uvicorn.exe` file in `C:\Python310\Scripts\`, which is what I'd expect given that most other things in that folder that can be called directly from cmd are executables. Then again, I'm not actually sure what is normal behaviour here as a first time uvicorn user.

The error is generated when I open up a command prompt and type `uvicorn`. Of course, `uvicorn my_app:app` doesn't work.

The following, however, does work:

```
Open command prompt   
> Python   
>>>import uvicorn   
>>>
```

I have not set up a virtual environment.

Any thoughts on what might be going on would be appreciated. The uvicorn front page simply suggests using pip and everything is all good to go. Can I not use the `uvirorn my_app:app` method to start uvicorn on Windows? The getting started docs only mention the one method of starting (there is mention of importing uvicorn into a script, but it's mentioned once, and not through any of the typical deployment patterns).

Comment: Looks like you might have installed uvicorn with pip in your user folder instead of folders mentioned above and this user folder is not in path.

Comment: I just did a system wide search for the exe and let it run for about 20 mins (let it run for 10 mins last night and gave up waiting). I think you're right. This seems to be an artefact of whatever has happened recently where pip seems to be required to run with the --user flag otherwise it throws permission errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

The main issue was that the Python 3.10.7 had been installed not for all users, but had been installed in a path in C:\ making it look like it was installed for all users. As @Bijay pointed out uvicorn was then installing via pip to the appdata\roaming\python directory instead of that which was mapped in the PATH variable. This was also the cause of some other permissions issues.

A full uninstall of python, manual cleanup of those directories and paths after uninstall, a restart, then a reinstall with the python installer using the custom and 'for all users' option resolved the issue. Install uvicorn with pip.